# Package tabfigures adds a spurious word "tabular"

Tags: luatex, memoir

I ran the MWE with

```
LuaTEX version 1.0.4TeX Live 2017/W32TeX
```

on a Windows 10 machine with Minion-Pro V2.112 makeotf.lib 2.5.5900.

I'm appending the file list!

In the MWE, I have commented out the \figureversion line and the example works, but the log file contains

```
Package tabfigures Warning: There is no \figureversion to support tabular 
figures on input line 15.
```

What would be the consequences of ignoring this warning?

When the line is uncommented, the warning disappears from the log file but each  enumerate line is now prefixed by the word "tabular" e.g.

```
tabular1. First item ;
```

The ToC behaves similarly.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, book]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Numbers={OldStyle,Proportional},Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase,Renderer=Basic]{Minion Pro}%

%\newcommand{\figureversion}{\addfontfeatures{Numbers=Monospaced}}

\usepackage[eqno,enum]{tabfigures} 

\usepackage{enumerate}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter One}

\section{Section A}

\begin{enumerate}
\item First item ; 
\item Another item ;
\item Last item ;
\end{enumerate}

\begin{threeparttable}[t]
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{S[table-format=3.2]}}
\toprule
1.2     &5.31   &100\\
99.0    &15.01  &8.4\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}

\end{document}
```

Filelist:

*File List*

```
  memoir.cls    2016/05/16 v3.7f configurable book, report, article document cla
ss
luatex85.sty    2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
  ifetex.sty    2011/12/15 v1.2 ifetex
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   mem11.clo    2008/01/30 v0.3 memoir class 11pt size option
mempatch.sty    2009/07/24 v6.0f Patches for memoir class v1.6180339
fontspec.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2017/12/16 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2017/12/16 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2017/12/16 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
fontspec-luatex.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
tabfigures.sty    2007/05/07 v0.1d Tabular figures (patches)
 siunitx.sty    2017/11/26 v2.7k A comprehensive (SI) units package
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
l3keys2e.sty    2017/12/16 LaTeX2e option processing using LaTeX3 keys
translator.sty    2018/01/04 v1.12 Easy translation of strings in LaTeX
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
threeparttable.sty    2003/06/13  v 3.0
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
siunitx-abbreviations.cfg    2017/11/26 v2.7k siunitx: Abbreviated units
 ***********
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit leandriis!  I was trying to do the same:-)

Comment: You're welcome. You can easily format code by selecting the lines and then press the `{}` button or use the shortcut `Ctrl+K`

Comment: For me the MWE works correctly (without errors/warnings and without extra output in the pdf) with both `xelatex` and `lualatex`, with or without the `\figureversion` line from the MWE. However, in the manual of the `tabfigures` package this error is stated differently, it mentions that `\tbfigures` is missing instead of `\figureversion` (manual/package v1.1 2012/01/24). Maybe it is a version problem?

Comment: Could you add the LuaTeX version to the question? And the output of putting `\listfiles` after `\documentclass{memoir}`? And the operating system (Windows/Mac/Linux), maybe the version of Minion Pro? Not everything may be relevant but it's better to have (slightly) too much information than too little.

Comment: tabfigures documentation says the package "can also be used as a companion to the fontspec package: if fontspec is loaded (and \tbfigures is not defined), this package defines \tbfigures as an alias for \addfontfeatures{Numbers=Monospaced}. In this way, tabfigures can also be used with XeTEEX and LuaTEX (provided a suitable OpenType font is loaded with fontspec)."  For me, XeLaTeX just hangs!

Comment: For me, XeLaTeX takes a very long time to run but produces the same spurious word "tabular" in the enumerate.  It does however format the table with a different style font (I'll check which is which).

Comment: @DLyons your version of `tabfigures` is very old (from 2007). The current version on CTAN is also old (2012) but still newer :) Can you try to update the package (with `tlmgr` would be the easiest)?

Comment: Yes, I just saw that.  It's odd because I have a version of tabfigures .sty that includes "Copyright (c) 2012 by Michael Ummels <michael.ummels@rwth-aachen.de>"  Apparently, the TexWorks version was installed by "collection-latexextra" (whatever that is!) and that won't let me uninstall tabworks.  I tried uninstalling all of  collection-latexextra but that's needed by "scheme-full" which sounds like a big update.

Comment: A workaround is to rename the newer file `mytabfigures.sty` and then in the document `\usepackage{mytabfigures}`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79554/discussion-between-dlyons-and-marijn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [commit 5638c3a](https://github.com/ummels/tabfigures/commit/5638c3a4a3accf3a1413433e617e447f8ac966b2) (September 2011) the implementation of the `tabfigures` package removed the `\figureversion` command:

```
 \AtBeginDocument{%
-  \@ifundefined{figureversion}{%
-    \PackageWarning{tabfigures}{There is no
-      \string\figureversion\space to support tabular figures}%
-    \let\Tf@font\@empty
+  \@ifundefined{tbfigures}{%
+    \PackageWarning{tabfigures}{There is no command
+      \string\tbfigures\space to support tabular figures}%
+    \let\tabfig@font\@empty
```

Using the latest version runs without errors:
[image]